# PHP Sql Check if foreach

Tags: php, sql, foreach, phpmyadmin

I want to check if any user in my Database has in categorie_bit a value of 0 or 1 and check this before my foreach.

I got this in my php script:

```
foreach ($database->query('SELECT id,firstname,lastname FROM `staff` WHERE categorie_bit = 1') as $resultRandom) {
    var_dump($resultRandom);
}
```

Pseudocode( I want something like this):

```
if(categorie_bit = 1) {
    foreach ($database->query('SELECT id,firstname,lastname FROM `staff` WHERE categorie_bit = 1') as $resultRandom) {
        var_dump($resultRandom);
    }
} else {
      echo "0";
}
```

Comment: I do not know what you mean

Comment: Not sure your pseudo code makes any sense. Could you describe in english what you want to do instead?

Comment: Sure, I want to check if any user in my Database has in categorie_bit a value of 0 or 1 before my foreach.

Comment: You cannot check the value of a column on a database table **before** you have read the row **from the table** Again makes no sense

Comment: So I have to put the condition inside my foreach and check if categoire_bit is 1 or 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "Sure, I want to check if any user in my Database has in categorie_bit a value of 0 or 1 before my foreach"

How about in your SQL

```
... WHERE categorie_bit = 1 OR categorie_bit = 0
```

or, this checks whether categorie_bit is set (assuming it can be 0, 1 or NULL)

```
WHERE categorie_bit IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same thing by iterating using a while loop instead of a `foreach`. At each iteration the `$row` variable is the row from the table:

```
$result = $database->query('SELECT * FROM `staff`');

while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { 

    if($row['categorie_bit'] == 0) {
        //Do something for 0's
    }    
    if($row['categorie_bit'] == 1) {
        //Do something for 1's
    }

}
```

Comment: I think this is probably what the OP wants to do but just in case the category bit can have other values I changed the code a bit. I hope you dont mind.

Comment: Your guess is as good as mine! Good point regarding other possible values, I was just assuming either 1's or 0's. Thanks!